# Disable outlook reminder via interop

Tags: c#, office-interop, outlook-addin

On my Outlook.AppointmentItem I've set the `ReminderSet` property to false, but when the recipients get the calendar hit, it does in fact have a reminder set.  How do I disable the reminder?

This is automation that's putting an OOO notice into the calendar so I'm marking it as Free time and definitely don't want a reminder popping up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set or unset a reminder for the attendees, it is a client side feature. The bets you can so is specify the intended free/busy status.